# Why, exactly, does reflexivity depend on the domain of the relation?

Tags: logic, relations

For many properties of binary relations, like symmetry, asymmetry, and transitivity, it does not depend on what domain of the relation we are considering. More precisely, given a binary relation $R$ on $A$ and a superset $B$ of $A$, $R$ is symmetric/asymmetric/transitive on $A$ iff it is so on $B$. However, reflexivity does depend on the domain. Why? Also, bonus question, is there a logical characterization of those properties which does not depend on the domain? That is, given a formula $F$ of first-order logic, what syntactic property must it have so that $R$ satisfies $F$ in a domain-independent way?

Comment: Well, one sufficient syntactic property is that it not explicitly refer to the domain ...

Comment: @NoahSchweber Although density (for any $(a,b)\in R$ with $a\neq b$, there is $c\in A$ with $c\neq a,b$ such that $(a,c),(c,b)\in R$) is also similarly extendible.

Comment: @Arthur That's why I said "sufficient."

Comment: I don't think this question is remotely as bad as the amount of downvotes would indicate. Would a downvoter care to explain their reasoning? Am I missing something?